Conference call(Many to many) in Flutter webrtc
I want to create a many-to-many call in Flutter webrtc.
I have created 1 v 1 using this repo
https://github.com/md-weber/webrtc_tutorial

i use Google sturn servers and share call data using firebase Everything is fine when I working on 1 v 1. but I don't know how to scale it up for many to many.
do you have any example or any idea to how to do it considering my code is like the tutorial above?
